# Two internet connection and one Local Area Network

Tags: networking, load-balancing

What solution do you think of following situation :-

Switch X, is connected to router A and router B. Where both routers are for internet connection.
Router A has DHCP running and have ip on lan 192.168.1.1/24.
Router B has DHCP running and have ip on lan 192.168.100.1/24.

Though these two are on same physical network, but logically are on different LANs.
Now let's call these LAN-1 and LAN-2 respectively.

How can one computer on LAN-1 connect to other computer on LAN-2.

Comment: Do you have 2 seperate networks these are running on?  how can you run 2 DHCP servers on the same physical network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide routing from LAN-1 to LAN-2 for interconnecting 2 networks.